# How to build a table (2D array) with variable column length in C?

Tags: c

Is it possible to build a table (2D array) with variable column length ?? and how can I make this if it is possible?

Here I have the code but the column length is fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h>


const int CITY = 2; // column number
const int WEEK = 2; // row number
int i,j;
int z=0;
int c[4]={1,2,3,4};
int main()
{
    int temperature[CITY][WEEK]; // create temp 2d array of city and weak
    for ( i = 0; i < CITY; ++i)
        {
        for( j = 0; j < WEEK; ++j) {
           temperature[i][j]= c[z];
           z++;
        }
    }

    printf("\nDisplaying values: \n\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < CITY; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < WEEK; ++j)
        {
            printf("City %d, Day %d = %d\n", i, j, temperature[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use an array of pointers, and each pointer can point to a different length row.

Comment: You allocate each row dynamically with `malloc()`.

Comment: You could use C99 or later 'variable length array' (VLA) notation.  `int n_cities = 23; int n_weeks = 14; int temperature[n_cities][n_weeks];` etc.  And the values 23 and 14 can be calculated at run-time before the array is defined — e.g. from user input.  The values need to be positive, and not too large (where 'too large' is not well defined, but is normally going to be OK if the total size of the array is not into the megabyte range).  If you need larger arrays, you need dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` et al).  You can still use the VLA notation, though.

Comment: Note that variables `i`, `j` and `z` (at minimum) should be local to `main()` and not global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of pointers which will point to arrays of different lengths.

```
int *p[row], i;

for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    p[i] = malloc(len * sizeof(int)); // len is length for row i
}
```

Then you can access the jth element of ith row by `p[i][j]`.

```
// displaying ith row of length = len

for ( j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
    printf("%d\n" p[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: how can access the jth element by  p[i][j]; >> it seems like conflicting types of p ?

Comment: sorry because i'm still a beginner in C  so i don't understand well ..now i'm ok with you in  point of that we assign a row length by pointers then how to  access is my confusing point ...?

Comment: Simply what i need to do is i have  like a 2 rows with 3 column ~~ TIME (2 bytes ) COMMAND(3 bytes )  DATA (5 bytes ) and then assign these bytes using a coming buffer of just a c buffer with int data ...